# How to return this query values

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I implement the join query for join two tables. How to return those values.

```
public List<cartItem> getcartItem(int userId)
    {


        var data = (from c in _context.cartItems join p in _context.Products
                    on c.productId equals p.ProId
                    where c.userId == userId && c.status==false select new {
                    proName=p.ProductName,
                    qty=c.quantity,
                    proImg=p.ImageUrl,
                    uPricce=p.price
                    }).ToList();

      
        return data;
       

    }
```

[image]

Comment: what is you are recomend?

Comment: Provide your code, as text, not a screenshot. And fully describe any errors you get, as text.

Comment: public List<cartItem> getcartItem(int userId)
        {


            var data = (from c in _context.cartItems join p in _context.Products
                        on c.productId equals p.ProId
                        where c.userId == userId && c.status==false select new {
                        proName=p.ProductName,
                        qty=c.quantity,
                        proImg=p.ImageUrl,
                        uPricce=p.price
                        }).ToList();

            return data;
        }

Comment: If. you want to return `cartItem`, make `select new cartItem {...}`. Not anonymous  object.

Comment: @MalshanHansaka Don't put long blocks of code into comments. All necessary information should be in the question itself. Please edit whatever you need into your question.

Comment: what is the return type of this code. i think query is currect. related data comming from database. but what is the return type and what is the best way to return those values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are the properties of a cartItem obj, you just need to assign the select statement to match the return type and new up a cartItem.

```
...select new cartItem 
{
   proName = p.ProductName,
   qty = c.quantity,
   proImg = p.ImageUrl,
   uPricce = p.price
}).ToList();
```